# Both XPath Variants Return Scrape Attempt With character (0)

Tags: html, r, xml, rvest

I have two issues scraping a page

I try to scrape a specific node with this code but it seems I cant get behind the general section of [1] and [2]

```
library(XML)
library(rvest)

page <- read_html("https://www.comaps.io/coin/tron")

titles = read_html(page) %>% html_nodes(css = '.mrktinfo')

page

{html_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>TRON (TRX) Marketcap, Volume, Pri ...
[2] <body>\n<div id="__next"><div class="allwrap">\n<div class="header-container flx-row">\n<div class="mobilesidebar-root" style="position:absol ...
```

Then, I tried to directly address a specific item with xpath

```
page <- read_html("https://www.comaps.io/coin/tron")

date <- page  %>% html_nodes(xpath='/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/ol/li[6]/p') %>% html_text() 
 

date <- page  %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="position_marketinfo"]/div[2]/ol/li[6]/p') %>% html_text()
```

Both attempts return

```
date
character(0)
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is pulled from a script tag. To get that target date you can use the following:

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

link <- "https://www.comaps.io/coin/tron"
page <- read_html(link)
data <- jsonlite::parse_json(page %>% html_node('#__NEXT_DATA__') %>% html_text())
print(data$props$pageProps$coin$sub$ico_launched)
```